# How to import AngularFireStorage from firebase cdn files in Angular App

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage, angular10

I am trying to use firebase from CDN files in my Angular App. My component looks below.

```
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';

constructor( private storage: AngularFireStorage  ) {}

uploadFile(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const filePath = 'my-path';
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
    const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
  }
```

CDN script I get from the Firebase console looks like below. This is pasted on `<head>` section in index.html:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>

<script>
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    ...
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.storageBucket();
</script>
```

Now, how do I import/use AngularFireStorage in app.component.ts? I use Angular 10.

What I tried?

```
declare let AngularFireStorage: any;
```

Comment: did you install the npm package?

Answer (score 0):

`AngularFire` is an npm package, since you are using angular then you already have a `node_modules` folder in your project. Then all you have to do is execute:

```
ng add @angular/fire
```

https://github.com/angular/angularfire

The following links:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

will add the firebase core and firebase storage javascript libraries. But the `angularfire` is not included above, thus you have to install the package to be able to use it.

---

The old, and not supported version of [angularfire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire) contained a cdn link:

```
<!-- AngularFire -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.3.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it throws an error something like `it missing dependency of firebase/app` thus require to install `firebase`. This is the reason to use cdn fully.

Comment: execute the following `npm install firebase`

Comment: Yes, but I want to use `firebase` from `CDN` only.